# Is there a way to initialize an array in Swift to have a repeated value of some Type T

Tags: swift, generics, swift-array

In my init function, I have:

```
 self.x = [T](count: dimensions, repeatedValue: 0)
```

This does not work. How do I get this to work.

I want x to be an array with type T that is initialized to 0. (T is intuitively like Int but could be some other number representation.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your code works, you just have to make sure `T` can be converted from `0` (`IntegerLiteralConvertible`)

```
func test<T: IntegerLiteralConvertible>(dimensions: Int) -> [T] {
    return [T](count: dimensions, repeatedValue: 0)
}

println(test(3) as [Int]) //[0, 0, 0]
println(test(3) as [Double]) //[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

---

or somehow make sure val have type of `T`

```
func test<T>(dimensions: Int, val: T) -> [T] {
    return [T](count: dimensions, repeatedValue: val)
}

println(test(3, 1)) //[1, 1, 1]
println(test(3, "a")) //[a, a, a]
```